# Построение диаграмм в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем доброго времени суток,столкнулся с такой проблемой,ни как не получается построить диаграмму(**chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries**) ,при чем круговая диаграмма(**chartingToolkit:PieSeries**) строится на ура...
XAML:

```
    <Window
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
            xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
            xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

        x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="1162" Width="1889">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.505,0.844" Margin="0,0,-8,19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1889">
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbFilter" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,410,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="25"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbFilterMode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,410,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <TextBlock>=</TextBlock>

            <TabItem/>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFilterValue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="225,409,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" Header="GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="890" Height="260">
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="245,10,-12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="230" Width="645"/>
        </GroupBox>

        <xctk:CheckListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,20,0,20" Width="450" ItemSelectionChanged="sss" />
        <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="pieChart" Margin="475,275,774,472">


            <chartingToolkit:PieSeries DependentValuePath="Value" 
IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />


        </chartingToolkit:Chart>










    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
private void UpdateChart(string mdxQuery)
        {
            // prepare adomd connection
            using (AdomdConnection mdConn = new AdomdConnection())
            {
                mdConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Сергей;Initial Catalog=MultidimensionalProject1";
                mdConn.Open();
                AdomdCommand mdCommand = mdConn.CreateCommand();
                mdCommand.CommandText = mdxQuery;  // << MDX Query 

                // выполняем запрос, получаем CellSet
                CellSet cs;
                cs = mdCommand.ExecuteCellSet();

                // our method supports only 2-Axes CellSets
                if (cs.Axes.Count != 2) return;

                TupleCollection tuplesOnColumns = cs.Axes[0].Set.Tuples;
                TupleCollection tuplesOnRows = cs.Axes[1].Set.Tuples;

                // 2 дублирующиеся структуры данных для графиков и таблицы с данными
                var Data = new DataTable();
                List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> ChartData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();







                if (tuplesOnColumns.Count > 0 && tuplesOnRows.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Создаем заголовки в таблице на основе названий
                    for (int m = 0; m < tuplesOnRows[0].Members.Count; m++)
                    {
                        Data.Columns.Add(tuplesOnRows[0].Members[m].ParentLevel.Name);
                    }

                    Data.Columns.Add(tuplesOnColumns[0].Members[0].Caption);

                    // Выводим строки с данными
                    for (int row = 0; row < tuplesOnRows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        int m = 0; string key = "";
                        // объект - для занесения в таблицу данных
                        var o = new object[tuplesOnRows[row].Members.Count + tuplesOnColumns.Count];

                        for (; m < tuplesOnRows[row].Members.Count; m++)
                        {
                            // заносим названия измерений для таблицы (по колонкам)
                            o[m] = tuplesOnRows[row].Members[m].Caption;
                            key += tuplesOnRows[row].Members[m].Caption + " ";

                        }
                        // заносим непосредственно значения метрики (кол-во обращений) в последнюю колонку строки (для таблицы)
                        for (int col = 0; col < tuplesOnColumns.Count; col++)
                        {
                            o[m + col] = (cs.Cells[col, row].Value.ToString());
                        }
                        //добавляем строку таблицы
                        Data.Rows.Add(o);
                        ChartData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(key, Convert.ToInt32(cs.Cells[0, row].Value)));




                    }
                }
                // обновляем визуализацию данных
                try
                {
                    dataGrid.ItemsSource = Data.DefaultView;
                    pieChart.DataContext = ChartData;



                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
```